# Links are not clickable due to CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where the links in my nav bar are not clickable unless I remove some CSS I've added.

Here is the snippet of CSS I need to remove to have clickable links:

```
.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

It seems to be related to `float: right;` because if I disable just that phrase the links become clickable.

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(zomb2.PNG);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-nav li.active {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.hero {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 275px;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 440px;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-one {
  background-color: darkorange;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-two {
  background-color: darkorange;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-two: hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>

    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">Learn More</a></li>
      <li><a href="zombies.html">Real Zombies</a></li>
      <li><a href="ordinance.html">Guns and Ammo</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.html">The Latest</a></li>
      <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hero">
    <h1> Real Zombie Vs. Human Battles </h1>
    <h2> Choose your side..</h2>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-one">Zombies</a>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-two">Humans</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help! I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't find it anywhere.. I searched around on here and couldn't find anything specifically that addressed this issue. Help!

Comment: Try using z-index. Hope that helps

Comment: `.hero { z-index: -1; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.hero` in `position:absolute` overlaps `header`, you can bring your links on top of it via `position:/* any value but static */` + `z-index`

```
a {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

demo:

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(zomb2.PNG);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.main-nav li.active {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.hero {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 275px;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 440px;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-one {
  background-color: darkorange;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-two {
  background-color: darkorange;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-two: hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">
    </div>

    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">Learn More</a></li>
      <li><a href="zombies.html">Real Zombies</a></li>
      <li><a href="ordinance.html">Guns and Ammo</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.html">The Latest</a></li>
      <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="hero">
    <h1> Real Zombie Vs. Human Battles </h1>
    <h2> Choose your side..</h2>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-one">Zombies</a>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-two">Humans</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried yours as well and it does seem like z-index corrects the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your css to

```
.main-nav
{
     float: right;
     list-style: none;
     margin-top: 30px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 10;
}
```

z-index should fix the issue. (but it wouldn't work without position set to relative)

for more information check out this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index